# Hashing of small dictionary

Tags: c, dictionary, hash, linked-list

I want to hash small dictionary ("dictionaries/small"). Main file compiles correctly, but at runtime it produces *"Segmentation fault"* message with function `insert()` (specifically something wrong with `malloc()`, but I don`t know what).

HASH.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char* name;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

node* first[26] = {NULL};

int hash(const char* buffer)
{
    return tolower(buffer[0]) - 'a';
}

void insert(int key, const char* buffer)
{
    node* newptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    strcpy(newptr->name, buffer);
    newptr->next = NULL;

    if (first[key] == NULL)
    {
       first[key] = newptr;
    }
    else
    {
        node* predptr = first[key];
        while (true)
        {
            if (predptr->next == NULL)
            {
                predptr->next = newptr;
                break;
            }
            predptr = predptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(newptr->name, buffer);`. The `name` fields has not been initialised and thus does not point to any valid memory. Either `malloc` memory for `name` or change it to be a fixed size array. e.g.  `newptr->name = strdup(buffer))`

Comment: but I initialised memory with malloc for node (and name and pointer to next node)

Comment: You allocated the space for the char pointer "name", not the array of character where it is supposed to point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `insert()` you correctly allocate the new node:

```
node* newptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

In this way you make room for a full struct node: a pointer to `node` and **a pointer to `char`**. But you don't allocate the space where those pointer are supposed to point.

So, when you copy the input buffer within `name` field, you are performing an illegal attempt to write to a  `char *` pointer that has not been allocated and not even initialized:

```
strcpy(newptr->name, buffer);
```

All pointers need to be allocated (or at least initialized to a valid memory location) before writing in them. In your case:

```
newptr->name = malloc( strlen( buffer ) + 1 );
if( newptr->name )
{
    strcpy(newptr->name, buffer);
}
```