# Printf for hash

Tags: c, dictionary, hash, linked-list

It's continue of [Hashing of small dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890233/hashing-of-small-dictionary). Now it's seems like hashing is working, but when I`m trying to display any bucket - there is "Segmentation fault" after displays of words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hash.c"
#include "dictionary.h"

#define LENGTH 45
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/small"


int main(void)
{
  char* dictionary = DICTIONARY;
  FILE* fd = fopen(dictionary, "r");
  char h[LENGTH];
  while(true)
  {
    char* c = fgets(h,sizeof(h),fd);
    if (c == NULL)
      {
         if ( feof (fd) != 0)
         {
            printf ("\nEOF\n");
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            printf ("\nERROR\n");
            break;
         }
      }
      int hashedValue = hash(c);
      //printf("%d\n", hashedValue);
      insert(hashedValue, c);
  }
node* ptr = first[6];  //trying to display any 
while(!NULL)
{
 printf("%s", ptr->name);
 ptr = ptr->next;
}

fclose (fd);
}
```

Comment: Your while loop has no escape route. Since `!NULL` will always be true, it will just keep running and running and then eventually your computer tells you segfault as a #$&* you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
while(!NULL)
```

with either

```
while ( ptr != NULL )
```

or

```
while ( ptr )
```

You want to make sure that `ptr` does not contain a `NULL` value before continuing.  `while(!NULL)` evaluates to `while(1)`, so the loop repeats "forever" (or until you try to access memory you don't own).